# If I connect two independent clauses with a semicolon, do the subjects of the two have to be the same?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, clauses, semicolons

ex:
Their motivations varied and often intertwined; but, whether it was due to a desire for glory, wealth and power, knowledge, or religious converts, the entire worldview of Europe and Asia radically shifted after these expeditions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, semicolons come between two *[interdependent](https://bickeringivy.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/ivy-tip-17/)* clauses.

Second, "but" is a coordinating conjunction.  Coordinating conjunctions introduce [*coordinate* clauses](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/coordinatingconjunction.htm).  Coordinate clauses are joined to the preceding main clause by a comma if they coordinate closely with it.  Or if not, a period is used.

Third, you don't provide enough context to give anyone any idea how closely related those clauses are because we don't know whom the possessive pronoun "their" refers to or how or if whomever "their" refers to is related to the entire worldview of Europe and Asia radically shifting after "these expeditions," whatever that's supposed to mean.

In answer to your question, I'm not going to say the subjects necessarily have to be the same because I can't imagine every situation, nor can I even imagine your situation as it is so vague.  I will, however, say that if you were to make them interdependent clauses, the "however" or other contrasting adverbial sentence connector you used would need to introduce a clause that somehow specifically contrasts or contradicts what the subject-verb in the preceding clause conveys in order to create the interdependence that is required to use a semicolon between two clauses properly.

Comment: For more context, this is the whole paragraph:
Late into the Renaissance and early into the Age of Discovery, the new monarchs had begun dispatching explorers beyond their respective borders into the unknown. Their motivations varied and often intertwined; but, whether it was due to a desire for glory, wealth and power, knowledge, or religious converts, the entire worldview of Europe and Asia radically shifted after these expeditions. Columbus was a part of one such voyage with a main focus of finding a faster trade route--west of Europe--to the markets of India and China.

Comment: Also about "but," are you saying to remove the comma between it and "whether?" (<---also, was I correct to put the punctuation at the inside of the quotations?)

Comment: You would use a period after "intertwined" because the coordinate clause that "but" introduces doesn't relate back to that which comes before it but instead relates back to the first sentence in the paragraph.  It is introducing the idea that the worldview of Europe and Asia radically shifting was somehow adverse to the action of monarchs dispatching explorers.

Comment: The sentence that starts with "Columbus was..." is either misplaced in the paragraph or should start a new paragraph.  I can't tell because I don't have enough context.  All I know is it doesn't form any logical next step from the sentence before it.

Comment: As for a comma after "but," it is a discretionary comma.  That comma is a question of style, and if you follow a style guide, like MLA, APA, Chicago Manual of Style, then you will need to look in that style guide to find out about whether to use a comma after a coordinating conjunction when it starts a sentence.  The most common practice I've seen is omitting the comma between a coordinating conjunction and an introductory modifier when the coordinating conjunction is preceded by a comma but including it when the coordinating conjunction starts a sentence.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I would upvote, but I lack the reputation.